# ol-cesium and osm buildings elevation

Tags: openlayers, openstreetmap, cesiumjs

Has anyone succeded to display a geojson model of osm buildings with height in 3d view on ol-cesium.
I tried the example provided by foss4g (https://github.com/gberaudo/talks/tree/master/2015-foss4g-seoul/examples/extrude) but the geojson layer is not displayed in 3D display (ol3d.setEnabled (true)).
I can not find any example that works on the web.
Someon can help me ?
Thanks

Comment: any working examples from your side until now? i am very interested in your answer to the question.

Answer (score -1):

The problem of the example is the terrain provider url is not working.

below code is from the example:

```
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
    url : '//cesiumjs.org/stk-terrain/tilesets/world/tiles'
});
```

You can use this url instead like this:

```
var terrainProvider = new Cesium.CesiumTerrainProvider({
    url : '//assets.agi.com/stk-terrain/world'
});
```

hope you can get it right